# ActiveMQ Artemis Error - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred

Tags: activemq-artemis

In ActiveMQ Artemis, I occasionally receive the connection error below. I can't see any obvious impact to the brokers or message queues. **Anyone able to advise exactly what it means or what impact it could be having?**

Current action performed is to either restart the brokers or check to see they're still connected to the cluster. **Is either of this action necessary?**

Current ActiveMQ Artemis version deployed is v2.7.0.

//error log line received at least once a month

```
   2019-05-02 07:28:14,238 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: *Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking* has occurred.
```

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, yes your answer is really helpful. I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error indicates that something on the network is connecting to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker, but it's not completing any protocol handshake. This is commonly seen with, for example, load balancers that do a health check by creating a socket connection without sending any real data just to see if the port is open on the target machine.

The timeout is configurable so that the `ERROR` messages aren't logged, but that will also disable the clean-up which may or may not be a problem in your use-case.  You should just be able to set `handshake-timeout=0` on the relevant acceptor URL in `broker.xml`.

When you see this message there should be no need to restart the broker.

In the next ActiveMQ Artemis release the IP address of the remote client where the connection originated will be included as part of the message.