# ActiveMQ Artemis Error - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking with LB

Tags: timeout, activemq-artemis

My question is related to the question already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949120/activemq-artemis-error-amq224088-timeout-10-seconds-while-handshaking-has-o)

Its indicated in the original post that the timeout happens about once a month. In our setup we are receiving this once every 10 seconds. Our production logs are filled with this handshake exception messages. Would setting the timeout value for handshake apply to our scenario as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Setting `handshake-timeout=0` on the relevant acceptor URL in your `broker.xml` applies here even with the higher volume of timeouts.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm seeing that the amqps acceptor already has this setting. My Artemis instance is behind a Network LB and connectivity is via port 5671. Is there a way to find out the origin of this exception?

Comment: As noted in [the answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949120/activemq-artemis-error-amq224088-timeout-10-seconds-while-handshaking-has-o), the latest versions of ActiveMQ Artemis will include the IP address of the client causing the timeout. Version 2.8 is the first version with this improvement.

Comment: I was referring to the amqps acceptor in scope of which I have the handshake-timeout=0 setting in the broker.xml file. However, I'm still seeing the timeout exception and am unsure which other acceptor is causing this timeout to occur. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no readily available way to identify the relevant acceptor involved in the handshake timeout. I'd recommend a simple process of elimination in your case.

Comment: FWIW I just sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/2873) to add the name of the acceptor to the error message so that should be available in the next release.

Comment: Thank you! That will be helpful.

Comment: I added handshake-timeout setting attribute to the artemis acceptor on port 61616 that enables clustering and saw the problem go away. Thank you Justin!